# Java consumer substitutes?

Tags: java, syntax, consumer

Where there is already a java substitute for this functional interface:

```
public interface FunctionA {
       public void run(Person person, Object target);
}
```

in the form of

```
BiConsumer<Person, Object>
```

is there one for this abstract class:

```
public abstract class ApplicationPlugin {

public abstract void init();

}
```

where usage is:

```
public class X extends ApplicationPlugin {
@Override public void init(){
    //stuff
}
}
```

Comment: Yes, `Runnable`.

Comment: No idea why this was tagged `assembly`, because I don't see any CPU instructions or Java bytecode-asm (which has its own tag: [tag:java-bytecode-asm]).  Was this supposed to be tagged [tag:.net-assembly]?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're looking for the [Runnable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) interface which has a single method taking no parameters and has a *void* return type.

e.g.

```
Runnable runnable = () -> doSomething();
```